# xPath, complicated foreach loop

Tags: php, html, xpath

I am using xPath to get a table , the table's first column has a link to another page, I want that link to link on the name column (first  column). Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($xpath->query('//*[@id="CRConcernedPersonel1_DataGridCRPersonel"]/tr') as $row) { 
 echo '<tr>';
   foreach($xpath->query('td[position() > 0]', $row) as $col) {
    echo '<td>'.trim($col->textContent).'</td>'; 
     foreach($xpath->query('a/@href', $col) as $link) 
        echo '<a href="'.trim($link->textContent).'"</a>'.'Link text'."\n";          
 }
 echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
```

Here is the output:

http://pastebin.com/5PjCae74

Thanks!

Comment: can we see the whole HTML file ?

Comment: http://www.moic2.gov.bh/eInvestor.Web/Web.UI.Pages/Inquiry/InquiryDetails.aspx?cm_cod=15490&br=1&Disp=2&inq=15490

My file is on localhost, but here is where I am reading from. Under Concerned Personnel.

Comment: What is the part you want to get help for? I don't see a question here, so better share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work when you change

```
 echo '<a href="'.trim($link->textContent).'"</a>'.'Link text'."\n";
```

to

```
 echo '<a href="'.trim($link->textContent).'">Link text</a>'."\n";
```

Currently your output reads e.g. like

```
<a href="CRDetails.aspx?PID=84539&Disp=1&inq=1"</a>Link text
```

therefore the link's not working. Changing the line as suggested should result in

```
<a href="CRDetails.aspx?PID=84539&Disp=1&inq=1">Link text</a>
```

Comment: +1: I don't see why this answer should get a down-vote.

Comment: @MarcusRickert Thanks, I'm not sure about that, too, just suspected kind of a revenge downvote as it happened shortly after reviewing low qual. posts, recommending deletion of some.